# How to pass non-python compatible arguments to rpy2 imported functions from R

Tags: rpy2

I have the following R-code that I would like to implement in rpy2:

```
surv_function <- Surv(data_frame$life, data_frame$survival==0)
```

So I tried using the `robjects.r()`method and it works fine, but I need to access the return of the function in python environment, so how can I pass the arguments `data_frame$life, data_frame$survival==0` if i use the following code in Python:

```
survival = importr('survival')
surv_function = survival.Surv(????)
```

So the problem is the `$` and `==0` parts of the argument.
What goes instead of '`????`' Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would the rpy2 documentation be helpful ?

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/introduction.html#linear-models